# BigQuery giving error of expression not grouped by when order by is included in the sql statement

Tags: google-bigquery

I am running a simple query in BigQuery.

```
SELECT
        p.title,
        p.id,
        SUM(view) Views,
        CAST(EXTRACT(DATE from pv.data_tstamp) as string) dateInserted
    FROM  products  p
    LEFT JOIN  productViews  pv
        ON p.sku=pv.sku WHERE
        pv.data_tstamp >= TIMESTAMP('2022-06-20 00:00:00') AND
        pv.data_tstamp  <= TIMESTAMP('2022-06-29 00:00:00') 
        GROUP BY p.title, p.id,
        CAST(EXTRACT(DATE from pv.data_tstamp) as string) order by p.Id
```

I am getting an error:

SELECT list expression references pv.data_tstamp which is neither grouped nor aggregated at [5:28]

pv.data_stamp is grouped by as can be seen in the syntax.

if i remove `order by p.id` It works fine, but I need the query to sort the result by Id.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

From the [BQ ORDER BY](https://cloud.google.com/bigquery/docs/reference/standard-sql/query-syntax#order_by_clause) doc:

> Column aliases from a FROM clause or SELECT list are allowed.
> If a query contains aliases in the SELECT clause, those aliases override names in the corresponding FROM clause.The data type of expression must be [orderable](https://cloud.google.com/bigquery/docs/reference/standard-sql/data-types#orderable_data_types).

In your case you have set **dateInserted**  as the alias name of the functional output  but then again in the `group by` clause you have used the same functional expression instead of the alias name.

This will work when you don't have any `order by` clause , but as soon as you use `order by` the query will only recognize the either selected **column names** or their **alias names**.

Thus in the `Select` statement of your query the **pv.data_tstamp** column name is no longer available as it has been overridden. Only **title**, **id**, **views**, **dateInserted** (and also the other columns which are not selected)column names are visible.

To remove the error, you need to either use `ordinals` or `alias name` in **group by** and **order by** clause

Eg:

```sql
SELECT
    p.title,
    p.id,
    SUM(view) Views,
    CAST(EXTRACT(DATE from pv.data_tstamp) as string) dateInserted
FROM  products  p
LEFT JOIN  productViews  pv
    ON p.sku=pv.sku WHERE
    pv.data_tstamp >= TIMESTAMP('2022-06-20 00:00:00') AND
    pv.data_tstamp  <= TIMESTAMP('2022-06-29 00:00:00') 
    GROUP BY p.title, p.id,dateInserted  -- replacing with ordinals will also work
    order by p.Id
```

You can play with this query to check what are the ways you can use both clauses together,

Answer (score 1):

First of all, working queries will be like below:

```sql
SELECT p.title,
       p.id,
       SUM(view) Views,
       CAST(EXTRACT(DATE from pv.data_tstamp) as string) dateInserted 
  FROM products  p
  LEFT JOIN  productViews  pv
    ON p.sku=pv.sku WHERE
       pv.data_tstamp >= TIMESTAMP('2022-06-20 00:00:00') AND
       pv.data_tstamp  <= TIMESTAMP('2022-06-29 00:00:00') 
 GROUP BY p.title, p.id, dateInserted -- using a column alias
 ORDER BY p.Id;
```

or using ordinal positions,

```sql
 GROUP BY 1, 2, 4 -- using ordinal positions
 ORDER BY p.Id;
```

---

If you remove an alias **dateInserted**, it will work also along with **ORDER BY** but a column name becomes anonymous.

```sql
SELECT ...
       CAST(EXTRACT(DATE from pv.data_tstamp) as string) -- removed alias
  FROM products  p
  LEFT JOIN  productViews  pv
    ON p.sku=pv.sku WHERE ...
 GROUP BY p.title, p.id, CAST(EXTRACT(DATE FROM pv.data_tstamp) AS STRING)
 ORDER BY p.Id;
```

What I don't understand is why **ORDER BY** makes an error as in the original post.  My best quess is that by adding **ORDER BY**, column aliases in **SELECT list** are freezed and it affects the scope of aliases in **GROUP BY** list.

Any thought on this ?

Comment: Yes, When we use order by then only the selected column names / alias names are visible in the whole query.